# Is there a category of 'shortage jobs' in either France, Belgium or Switzerland, and is it easier to get permits for them if you qualify?

Tags: working-visas, france, resident-permit, switzerland, belgium

From the links:

http://www.bluecard-eu.de/eu-blue-card-germany/, and 
https://www.apply.eu/BlueCard/Luxembourg/

it appears that in Luxembourg and Germany, there's a category of 'shortage jobs' that goes in favor of non-EU people to have not so high salary in order to obtain EU Blue Card. That is, they could earn less than the minimum salary requirement for a Blue Card, and can still apply for and get one. However, I don't see the same in the corresponding links for France, Belgium or Switzerland (which doesn't issue a Blue Card but does give selected permanent residence and work permit etc.)

My question is: even if it's not mentioned, is there a category of 'shortage jobs' for France, Belgium and Switzerland that'd go in favor of non-EU people applying for positions in those 'shortage areas'?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative but, in the case of France, I can't find any reference to an exception in the relevant official sites (including [service-public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/actualites/A10765), which is usually comprehensive and up-to-date) so the answer appear to be "no".

Comment: @Gala Thanks for the comment and the reference! Yes, I see that it's pretty rigid in the case of France.